# How can I check to see if user has exited the app?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

How can I check if user has exited the app, so I can make sure the app will shutdown?

I am currently using Swift - Xcode 6.3.1

Comment: In most cases, system will take care of the shutdown for you and you don't have to implement it yourself. So just to make it clear: Are you talking about OS X application or iOS application? Do you want to be notified when the user exits the app, or implement your own exit button?

Comment: I am using iOS Swift

Comment: By exit do you mean the user pressing home button or quoting you app by swiping up. If you mean the home button press; your app is backgrounded and might be terminated by system if needed. If you mean to do any cleanup or data protection when the user press home button; deal with that in some few seconds in app delegates applicationDidEnterBackground:

Answer (score 6):

In the AppDelegate class (`AppDelegate.m`) there is a function called `applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification*)notif`. This function will be called when the application has been quit. This is where you put any code that you have to call before quitting the app (e.g. closing files, deleting timers, etc). This is automatically called when the app closes, you don't have to check yourself.

Comment: See also applicationDidEnterBackground for when the user leaves the app (e.g. pressed the home button) but it has not yet terminated.

Comment: Assuming of course that it's an iOS app. For OS X you need to detect when the window loses focus, but that's another matter.

Comment: @AliBeadle How would I terminate the app!

Comment: This method rarely gets called. @AliBeadle is along the right lines.

Answer (score 4):

In iOS you don't (in general) terminate an app. You should design your app such that if the user moves away from it (e.g. presses the Home button) that it is ready for when they decide to come back. You also need to design it such that if iOS terminates it (e.g. due to memory limitations) that no user data is lost and that all is right next time the app launches (the general guidance here is that the user cannot tell that the app terminated - but a lot of apps don't succeed in that). But otherwise you do not need to do anything when the user 'goes away' from your app.

See [this Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/_index.html) for the official line on not terminating. See [this Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html) for more details on the App lifecycle in iOS.

The sole exception is that you may want to terminate if a fatal error occurs - in Swift you can use fatalError to do this, but it will look like a crash to your user.